# StackOverflow on `forever` Combinator

Tags: scala, stack-overflow, combinators

Looking at the `forever` combinator from [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/):

```
trait AddlCombinators[F[_]] extends Monad[F] with Functor[F] {
      def forever[A, B](a: F[A]): F[B] = {
        lazy val t: F[B] = forever(a)
        flatMap(a)(_ => t)
      }
}
```

I ran into a StackOverflow, as the book explains.

Then, I added a `count` variable, incrementing it each time `t` gets accessed:

```
var count = 0
def forever[A, B](a: F[A]): F[B] = {
  lazy val t = { println(count); count = count + 1; forever(a) }
}
```

Then, I created a ScalaTest test:

```
 "running forever" should "throw a StackOverflow exception" in {
        val listCombinator = new AddlCombinators[List] {

        // omitted implementation of `Monad[List]` and `Functor[List]`
        }    
        listCombinator.forever(List(1))
      }
}
```

After running the above test 3 times, it fails on ~1129/1130 each time.

```
1129
[info] TestCombinators:
[info] running forever
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last test:testOnly for the full output.
[error] Could not run test test.TestCombinators: java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Why is it getting up to that number before crashing? Also, how can I reason about how much stack memory each execution of `forever` is taking up?

Answer (score 2):

It gets up to that number because of the stack size. The size can be set with `-Xss` and the default values differ depending on the platform and VM/Version. But in general when you get a `StackOverflowError` you should try to fix the problem in your code and not your settings. In this case I would use trampolining to prevent the stack from overflowing. A very good explanation can be found here: http://blog.higher-order.com/assets/trampolines.pdf